# Laravel php artisan migrate command not working

Tags: laravel-5, migration, database-migration

i have install laravel 5.4 and trys to migrate a table.but migrate is not working.there is no errors showing.i have edited my env file correctly and also databse.php. what can be the reason?

my env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8000
DB_DATABASE=vim
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

migration script

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Screenshots of the migration script and also the terminal output after you've run `php artisan migrate` would help add more context.

Comment: @krain i have update the question

Comment: @krain143 i have update the question

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show any output...

Comment: @Niraj Shah yes there is no errors showing

Comment: It must be producing some output. Even if it just returns to saying `PS C:\...>`

Comment: Show config/database.php file please

Comment: try using normal cmd, not PS. If you want powerful cmd, I suggest you use `conemu` https://conemu.github.io/